# Is my disk partitioned correctly for cloning with Clonezilla?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, clone, clonezilla

I want to clone Windows from a 500GB HDD to a 240GB SSD. I already shrunk the partitions to fit the drive. In the photo you can see the partition structure - I'm worried that one of the recovery partitions is not togeter with the other partitions, but separated with free space to the left and right of it.
Can I clone the drive like that with clonezilla or do I have to move it with Gparted?
I want to use open-source software.
[image: Photo of disk management in win 10]

Comment: I think it depends on the mode/approach of cloning. If it allows you to do multiple partition cloning where it will form the new partition table for you then it should do. (You probably need to fix the MBR with `bootsect.exe` though, and/or the BCD with `bcdboot.exe` or `bcdedit.exe`.)

Comment: *So before cloning I should run bcdboot and bcdedit? I have a gpt drive.

Comment: Nah after. If the partition have different GUIDs you need to update the BCD for Windows Boot Manager to boot the cloned system partition. Or you can use the original GUIDs (probably need to get and set them with gdisk), but in that case better unplug the original drive before booting the clone.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is that of the original disk, there shouldn't be any problem in cloning
it to the new disk.

I would counsel using a blank target disk, to let the cloning software allocate the
partitions as required.

I would also counsel to use a Windows-oriented cloning product rather than one that
is based on Linux.

For example, in order of recommendation:

- [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
- [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)
- [Paragon Backup & Recovery Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/br-free/#)